# Русский язык как фундаментальная основа компьютерной начинки

Tags: архитектура, железо, кириллица, локализация, машинный-код

Какие **фундаментальные** аппаратные и программные ограничения могут возникнуть перед разработчиками ПО, в задачу которых входит разработка систем, использующих кириллицу, как основной набор символов, взамен распространённым ASCII кодам?

P.S. И существуют ли примеры подобных русифицированных систем?

Comment: По-моему, фундаментального тут ничего нет. Таблице кодов соответствует таблица символов. Если принять кирилличный стандарт типа ASCII, то и проблем не будет. Проблема в том, что нет такого единого стандарта. ASCII регламентирует только 7 бит (полтаблицы), дальше - есть вариации.

Comment: Основное (и единственное) фундаментальное ограничение состоит в том, что это никому не нужно.

Comment: Ограничение, по сути, одно — ослабленная совместимость с ASCII-only-системами. Многие существующие низкоуровневые системы построены без (довольно сложной) поддержки Unicode, многие программы на C/C++ до сих пор не умеют подсчитать длину кириллической строки в символах. Поскольку ASCII-систем много, это скорее всего приведёт к проблемам.

Comment: а как же 1С....

Comment: Имхо надо раз и навсегда забить в железо 16 бит на символ и использовать Unicode - тогда проблем не будет

Comment: @Barmaley нет, мы забьём всё пространство Юникода смайликами и мемами и перестанем помещаться в 16 битах на символ. 

Comment: Даже китайские иероглифы все поместились в юникод, не то что ваши смайлики :)

Comment: @Barmaley пока место есть, будут искать чем его занять. А отдельные разновидности смайликов можно множить экспоненциально, если вводить им всякие свойства вроде пола и цвета кожи. Можно разве что надеяться, что люди, стоящие за стандартом, такой ерунды не допустят.

Comment: Эмодзи уже добавили :)

Comment: @Barmaley я на них и намекаю, начало уже положено :)

Comment: @Barmaley Юникод больше, чем 16 бит. И даже [иероглифы не все в 16 бит поместились](https://unicode-table.com/en/#cjk-unified-ideographs-extension-b).

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну да уже отстал от жизни :) В Юникоде уже больше 64k символов, но с точки зрения Java Юникод все равно остается 16 бит, остальные 120k-64k символы [рассматриваются как supplementary](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/supplementary-142654.html)